# Multiselect in React Component - how to set state with all selected values?

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, multi-select

I have problem with adding all selected values to the state (hooks). This is example of my code:

```
   <div className="row">
        <div className="input-field col s12">
          <select multiple onChange={props.handleSelectedMultiple} id="balcony">
            <option value="" disabled>
              Brak
            </option>
            <option value="Balkon">Balkon</option>
            <option value="Taras">Taras</option>
            <option value="Ogród">Ogród</option>
            <option value="Loggia">Loggia</option>
            <option value="Taras na dachu">Taras na dachu</option>
          </select>
          <label>Balkon</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and function:

```
 const handleSelectedMultiple = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
```

The problem is that in console.log apears the value from FIRST SELECTED OPTION, so when I choose in this order Taras, Ogród, Loggia, in console i have (3)Taras. The goal is to add to state all selected values.

Anyone?

Comment: it works fine for me i am getting the values properly like this

Comment: Taras
test.js:4 Ogród
test.js:4 Loggia
test.js:4 Taras na dachu
test.js:4 Taras
test.js:4 Balkon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the selected options. You can do something like

```js
const handleSelectedMultiple = evt => {
    const values = Array.from(evt.target.selectedOptions, option => option.value);
    // Or this way
   // const values = [...evt.target.selectedOptions].map(opt => opt.value)
    console.log('values', values);
  };
```